# Detect when Android kills an AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

If I have an AsyncTask running indefinitely and Android decides it needs to kill the task either to free up memory or because the device is going into sleep mode (the user presses the power button), is there some way within the AsyncTask to get a notice from the OS that it is about to be killed off, so that action can be taken to complete any outstanding task?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. My question isn't about the length of operations. It's about detecting the killing of a thread.

Comment: You can't detect killing of a thread, maybe this callback will be helpful: ```Application.onLowMemory()```

Comment: What about using  AsyncClass.isCancelled() - Returns true if this task was cancelled before it completed normally OR  AsyncClass.cancel(boolean) - Attempts to cancel execution of this task??

Comment: I highly doubt the OS will call cancel before it terminates your thread. Would be nice if there was an AboutToDie method that gets called by the OS that gives you a few hundred milliseconds to pack up and leave Dawson ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To give you a short answer:

an AsyncTask lives as long as the process it is tied to lives. The OS will never kill an AsyncTask if its process is still running (even in background).

Also please note that the AsyncTask runs independently from the Activity that started it. The Activity may be destroyed and the AsyncTask still lives until the process is destroyed.

EDIT 
You need to call the isCancelled() inside the doInBackground() method in order to make sure that when the AsyncTask is destroyed by the OS, the doInBackground finishes so that the onCancelled() method is executed.

So to sum it up: in the doInBackground method always check the isCancelled boolean function. If it returns true, then return from the doInBackground. Automatically, the onCancelled function will be executed instead of onPostExecute. There you may place the code you want to execute prior to its death.

Comment: I don't believe that that is true. The OS will certainly kill anything it deems necessary, even a foreground service under severe conditions. If the OS is capable of killing a foreground service, it certainly isn't going to think twice about destroying an AsyncTask.

Comment: In "severe conditions" it will kill the entire process. It cannot kill the AsyncTask alone.

Comment: Also you should keep a reference to the AsyncTask and check it whenever you need to know if it's still alive.

Comment: Still, you haven't answered the question. If the AsyncTask is going to be killed, is there some way it can know that moments prior to its death?

Comment: There is nothing in the docs that indicates that you'll even have a chance of calling isCancelled once the OS decides to terminate it. In all likelihood, your task is terminated on the spot regardless what state it currently is in. isCancelled is used after some external client has safely terminated the task.

Comment: have you actually tried all these stuff or do you just deny anything?